# Can not I make a perfect fixed menu

Tags: html, menu, fixed

I want to make a fixed menu in HTML and it does not turn out very well for me, my menu is on the slider and I want it to scroll and emerge and have color. I just managed to keep it floating by placing it in the CSS position: fixed, does anyone know how I can do it?

Beforehand thank you very much.

[slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPM2G.jpg)

Comment: What you tried for far to achieve this?

Comment: I added in the css of the .menu-wrapper position: fixed. I want almost the same as they did on this page: http://ishothim.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use list to make ur menu.. then in css give each list element float:left. Also use a div tag make sure to put ur list in div tag... position:fixed auto